# Installing gedit with Homebrew on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: terminal, homebrew, macos-sierra, gedit, homebrew-cask

I am trying to install gedit on Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6.
Using **brew install gedit** it runs through the whole process with a few warnings and errors, including finishing with

*Error: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.*

I also tried **brew cask install gedit** but the error is *Error: Cask 'gedit' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists. Did you mean “ssh-config-editor”?*

Is there a way of installing a version of Gedit for Mac OSX Sierra? I read the cask option would work for Sierra. I realise some functions won't work but hopefully for what I am using for I won't need those.